# Bootstrap / ngx-bootstrap - drop down mutiple checkbox option

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, styles, ngx-bootstrap

On our current Angular 5 project, we use `bootstrap 3.3.7` and `ngx-bootstrap 2.0.3`

I have been asked to implement a dropdown multi-select option as shown below. It will allow user to select multiple options from dropdown list.

[image]

How can I implement this feature?

Comment: [Serigne Fatty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13460870) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66024355) saying "There are a few npm packages handling this right now : https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap-multiselect"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out neither of these frameworks support such component.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dropdown using [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns) and then add `<input type="checkbox"` with labels for a description within in menu item `li`.